# Audio issue with pcm_bluray when creating BD-Video using ffmpeg, tsMuxer and Xorriso

Tags: ffmpeg

1. ffplay and VLC can playback HDV.m2t source camcorder clips joined with cat. That is video and audio seamingly works with this ffplay output:

   ffplay -hide_banner HDV01.m2t
   [mpegts @ 0x7f82c4000cc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none ([160][0][0][0] / 0x00A0)): unknown codec
   Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
   [mpegts @ 0x7f82c4000cc0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Unknown: none ([161][0][0][0] / 0x00A1)): unknown codec
   Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
   Input #0, mpegts, from 'HDV01.m2t':
   Duration: 01:02:20.32, start: 0.440000, bitrate: 26168 kb/s
   Program 100
   Stream #0:0[0x810]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Side data:
   cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 25000000/0/0 buffer size: 7340032 vbv_delay: N/A
   Stream #0:1[0x814]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s
   Stream #0:2[0x815]: Unknown: none ([160][0][0][0] / 0x00A0)
   Stream #0:3[0x811]: Unknown: none ([161][0][0][0] / 0x00A1)
   23.04 A-V: -0.022 fd=   0 aq=   47KB vq= 3588KB sq=    0B f=0/0
2. The HDV.m2t camcorder sources are itself mpeg2 BD-video compliant and can be copied as is without re-encoding. The MP2 audio needs to be transcoded using pcm_bluray in my case and ffmpeg 6.1 on openSUSE Leap 15.5.

   ffmpeg -hide_banner -i HDV01.m2t -c:v copy -c:a pcm_bluray -mpegts_m2ts_mode 1 HDV-01.mts

Also this BD-compliant mts stream playback fine with ffplay

```
ffplay -hide_banner HDV-01.mts
[mpegts @ 0x7f2174000cc0] stream 1 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
Input #0, mpegts, from 'HDV-01.mts':
  Duration: 01:02:38.24, start: 1.440000, bitrate: 27883 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 25000000/0/0 buffer size: 7340032 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: pcm_bluray ([128][0][0][0] / 0x0080), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
   7.79 A-V: -0.023 fd=   0 aq=  221KB vq= 3161KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

3. The mts files are accepted as input in tsMuxer to create BD-Video iso, which next is used to burn the BD-video structure to BD-R disks with Xorriso.

   tree -sh /run/media/terje/HDV-01+02+03_BD
   /run/media/terje/HDV-01+02+03_BD
   ├── [ 520]  BDMV
   │   ├── [  40]  AUXDATA
   │   ├── [ 288]  BACKUP
   │   │   ├── [  40]  BDJO
   │   │   ├── [  92]  CLIPINF
   │   │   │   └── [141K]  00000.clpi
   │   │   ├── [ 120]  index.bdmv
   │   │   ├── [ 290]  MovieObject.bdmv
   │   │   └── [  92]  PLAYLIST
   │   │       └── [ 402]  00000.mpls
   │   ├── [  40]  BDJO
   │   ├── [  92]  CLIPINF
   │   │   └── [141K]  00000.clpi
   │   ├── [ 120]  index.bdmv
   │   ├── [  40]  JAR
   │   ├── [  40]  META
   │   ├── [ 290]  MovieObject.bdmv
   │   ├── [  92]  PLAYLIST
   │   │   └── [ 402]  00000.mpls
   │   └── [  92]  STREAM
   │       └── [ 37G]  00000.m2ts
   └── [  88]  CERTIFICATE
   └── [  40]  BACKUP

   14 directories, 9 files
4. ffplay and VLC does also playback video and audio ok directly from the BD-Video disc

   ffplay -hide_banner /run/media/terje/HDV-01+02+03_BD/BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts
   [mpegts @ 0x7fbbf0000cc0] stream 0 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
   [mpegts @ 0x7fbbf0000cc0] stream 2 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
   [mpegts @ 0x7fbbf0000cc0] stream 3 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
   [mpegts @ 0x7fbbf0000cc0] stream 5 : no PTS found at end of file, duration not set
   Input #0, mpegts, from '/run/media/terje/HDV-01+02+03_BD/BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts':
   Duration: 01:02:30.04, start: 4200.000000, bitrate: 83837 kb/s
   Program 1
   Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Side data:
   cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 25000000/0/0 buffer size: 7340032 vbv_delay: N/A
   Stream #0:1[0x1012]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Side data:
   cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 25000000/0/0 buffer size: 7340032 vbv_delay: N/A
   Stream #0:2[0x1013]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
   Side data:
   cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 25000000/0/0 buffer size: 7340032 vbv_delay: N/A
   Stream #0:3[0x1100]: Audio: pcm_bluray (HDMV / 0x564D4448), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
   Stream #0:4[0x1101]: Audio: pcm_bluray (HDMV / 0x564D4448), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
   Stream #0:5[0x1102]: Audio: pcm_bluray (HDMV / 0x564D4448), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
   4222.27 A-V: -0.000 fd=   4 aq=  205KB vq= 3160KB sq=    0B f=0/0
5. However, playback the disc in a standalone Blu-ray video player, doesn't find the audio.
   Is here possibly a mapping problem that can be solved during transcoding 2) above?
6. Another second issue I discovered just now without exploring it more yet:
   Three mts files were loaded as input to tsMuxer, resulting in the
   [ 37G]  00000.m2ts stream above.
   But so far I didn't succeed to access more than the first 12G stream....?
   Any ideas what has happened here ?